# How to check quatity of stock using Delegates and EventHandlers?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

**Brief:** I'm trying to create a basic application where a user enters the number of phones in stock and if a salesperson sell the phone, the inventory level should go down accordingly. Once it's reached the threshold, the salesperson should be notified.
So far I have created an application where it will notify the salesperson once it reaches the threshold but what I want is that after every sale, it should notify how much phones are left in stock.

**Question:** How do I check the `remaining quantity` left in stock  in output after each sale?

> For example: If I have 4 phones in stock and if I sell 1 it should say
>   only 3 phones left in stock and then 2 and then 1 and then a message that you have reached your threshold.

**Here's my code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of phone in stock:");
        int s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Counter c = new Counter(s);
        c.ThresholdReached += c_ThresholdReached;      
        for (int w = 0; w < s; w++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Do you want to buy a phone? Press 'Y' for Yes and Press 'N' for No");
               if (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar == 'y')
               {
                        Console.WriteLine("A phone has been sold");
                        c.Sub(1); 
                   // how should I check the remaining stock left now? 
               }
            }

    }
    static void c_ThresholdReached(Object sender, ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total {0} phones were sold at {1}.", e.Threshold,
        e.TimeReached);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
class Counter
{
    private int threshold;
    private int total;
    public Counter(int passedThreshold)
    {
        threshold = passedThreshold;
    }
    public void Sub(int x)
    {
        total += x;
        if (total >= threshold)
        {
            ThresholdReachedEventArgs args = new ThresholdReachedEventArgs();
            args.Threshold = threshold;
            args.TimeReached = DateTime.Now;
            OnThresholdReached(args);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThresholdReachedEventHandler handler = ThresholdReached;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    public event ThresholdReachedEventHandler ThresholdReached;
}
public class ThresholdReachedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Threshold { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeReached { get; set; }
}
    public delegate void ThresholdReachedEventHandler(Object sender,
ThresholdReachedEventArgs e);
}
```

Comment: Your "Question" is a statement.  What is your question?

Comment: Your Counter class just counts, it is incapable of keeping track of how many items remain in stock.  So of course you can't get this info.  You'll have to improve the class first.

Comment: @PeterRitchie **How do I show the remaining phones left in stock in output after  each sale?**

Comment: @samjohal do you want to get an event about the threshold reached or do you want to check the counter quantity?  If you want the event, you need to set the correct threshold.  You're setting it to # in stock that you've gotten from the user.  I assume that should be `total` and you should be asking for the threshold too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can display remaining phones. Change the `counter` class as below.

```
class Counter
{
    //make them public properties
    public int Threshold { get; set; } 
    public int Total { get; set; }

    //rest of the code in counter class....
```

In the `main` method, use simple Math. Put below line under the `c.Sub(1);`

```
 Console.WriteLine("total phones left {0}", (c.Threshold - c.Total));
```

I hope this will help you.